# Get ActionBar upIntent to act like the back button

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, fragment

I'm making this project where i have 3 fixed tabs in my MainActivity. On tab 2 and 3, I have buttons which will navigate the user to a new fragment activity. In the fragment activities I have used the ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true). My problem is that I want to take the user back to the former fragment (which is done now with both up button in the action bar and with the back button), but I want to get the user to the tab they were on before. When I use the back button to go up, I will get to the tab from where i started the new fragment. But when i use the upIntent in the action bar i get to tab 1. How can i solve this?

This is my code from the fragment activities where the upIntent action bar buttons are found.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent upIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
                TaskStackBuilder.from(this)
                        // If there are ancestor activities, they should be added here.
                        .addNextIntent(upIntent)
                        .startActivities();
                finish();
            } else {
                NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
            }
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i managed to find a solution to this. I changed to onOptionsItemSelected boolean to this:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        ClassName.this.finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```